# Optimize Postgresql Function Fiscal Month Date

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I've written the below function that is used in conjunction with the below table that stores a company's fiscal month definitions, however this function seems to be fairly slow when used to aggregate data by fiscal month. Can anyone give some pointers on how I can speed things up?

**Edit: I am still having some bottlenecks with this function. I have rewritten it to remove some fluff, but it is still significantly slower than just joining on the fiscal_months table in my queries. However I'd still rather use a function for ease of use, and so I don't have to rewrite a few dozen queries that are still using it.**

<s>CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_fiscal_month(date)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM $1) < 2008 THEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM $1)::integer
            ELSE
                (SELECT month FROM fiscal_months WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM $1) = year AND $1 >= start_date AND $1 <= end_date)
        END
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
      COST 100;</s>

**EDIT : May 6, 2014 (Rewrote function to be slightly faster)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_fiscal_month(date)
    RETURNS integer AS
    $BODY$
    SELECT month FROM fiscal_months WHERE $1 >= start_date AND $1 <= end_date
    $BODY$
LANGUAGE sql STABLE
COST 1000;
```

**Changes**
1. Removed CASE WHEN date is < 2008 (I don't have any data before 2008 anyway)
2. Removed WHERE (EXTRACT YEAR FROM date) = year (this is an unnecessary step)
3. Changed VOLATILE TO STABLE
4. Changed Cost from 100 to 1000

<s>CREATE TABLE fiscal_months
    (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      year integer NOT NULL,
      month integer NOT NULL,
      start_date date NOT NULL,
      end_date date NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT fiscal_months_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT fiscal_months_ukey UNIQUE (year, month)
    )</s>

```
CREATE TABLE fiscal_months
(
id serial NOT NULL,
year integer NOT NULL,
month integer NOT NULL,
start_date date NOT NULL,
end_date date NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fiscal_months_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fiscal_months_ukey UNIQUE (year, month),
CONSTRAINT fiscal_months_ukey_end UNIQUE (end_date),
CONSTRAINT fiscal_months_ukey_start UNIQUE (start_date)
)

CREATE INDEX fiscal_months_index_bothdates
    ON fiscal_months USING btree (start_date, end_date);

CREATE INDEX fiscal_months_index_test2
    ON fiscal_months USING btree (start_date);
```

**Changes**
1. Added indexes per comments below from SO users.

**Table Stats**
Sequential Scans    48018264
Sequential Tuples Read  4006572336
Index Scans 3251027 
Index Tuples Fetched    27236663
Tuples Inserted 0
Tuples Updated  0
Tuples Deleted  0
Tuples HOT Updated  0
Live Tuples 86
Dead Tuples 0
Heap Blocks Read    3047
Heap Blocks Hit 51266249
Index Blocks Read   13
Index Blocks Hit    3251026 
Toast Blocks Read
Toast Blocks Hit
Toast Index Blocks Read
Toast Index Blocks Hit
Last Vacuum 2014-05-05 16:46:54.087489-05
Last Autovacuum
Last Analyze    2014-05-06 13:23:47.709653-05
Last Autoanalyze    2014-05-05 16:47:29.248862-05
Table Size  8192 bytes
Toast Table Size    none
Indexes Size    96 kB

**Example Data**
Year Month Start_Date      End_Date
---- ----- ----------     ---------
2014   1   "2014-01-01"   "2014-01-24"
2014   2   "2014-01-25"   "2014-02-21"
2014   3   "2014-02-22"   "2014-03-28"
2014   4   "2014-03-29"   "2014-04-25"
2014   5   "2014-04-26"   "2014-05-23"
2014 6 "2014-05-24" "2014-06-27"

<s>p.s. I am using Postgresql 8.3</s>
p.s. I am using Postgresql 8.4

Comment: Add unique indexes to both the `start_date` and `end_date` fields.

Comment: The select statement in the else clause is the culprit in slowing this function...you will want to change the statement to a single select and not two like it is here.

Comment: @Twelfth: How can you tell? I don't doubt you by the way, but I want to learn.

Comment: @Declan_K, do you mean create 1 index with both date cols in it, or 2 indexes (1 for each col)? Also, does the type of index matter (btree, hash, etc?).

Comment: I would go with two seperate unique indexes.

Comment: select statements inside the select line in a query never preforms well, you are basically incurring a second query to occur for every record that goes through this.  2 queries will rarely (almost never) outpreform 1 query.

Comment: I don't think the select inside the column list here will harm things and may in fact perform better for the reason that the outer query merely uses a CASE statement to decide what to run.

Comment: Any comment since I updated my post?

Answer (score 4):

What data is in that reference table? Fiscal months can generally be determined from a date without recourse to a lookup.

For example, if your fiscal year 2012 runs from April 2012 to March 2013, you determine the current fiscal month with:

```
to_char(date_trunc('month',current_date) - interval '3' month, 'YYYY MM')
```

I would look at implementing the algorithm in this manner, preferably in SQL (and with your use of CASE of course, as it looks like the fiscal month logic changed in 2009).

Comment: I edited/updated my post to show some example data. I am not sure I can calculate it on the fly like you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> I've written the below function that is used in conjunction with the below table that stores a company's fiscal month definitions, however this function seems to be fairly slow when used to aggregate data by fiscal month. Can anyone give some pointers on how I can speed things up?

I think your problem is in how you are using this function.  If you are aggregating data in this way, you are denying the planner an ability to join with fiscal_month().

What you should be doing IMO, is calling fiscal_month() in a UNION portion of your aggregation query *only if* the `data >= '2008-01-01'`.  Encapsulating this in a function means that it may not be inlineable, and consequently instead of being able to do, say, a hash join, you are stick with a nested loop which is almost certainly where your problem is.

Comment: Please have a look at my revised post above, I added a lot more detail.

Comment: Yes I am aggregating using this function. E.g. SELECT get_fiscal_month(mydate) AS m, COUNT(*) AS v FROM sometablewithadate GROUP BY m ORDER BY m